# Getting Firefox to stretch an input properly

Tags: css, firefox

This is a simplified version of something I'm trying to do.  Works in every browser other than FF:

http://jsfiddle.net/hDFnW/10/

Basically, I'm trying to get an input to apply `width:auto;` when `position:absolute;left:200px;right:0px` is set.

It works on anything *other* than an input... I'm rather confused right now.

How can I accomplish this in Firefox, or better yet, across all browsers?

Comment: It's an inline element by default; thus it's not going to act like a div out of the box: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap the `input` with a `div` and then it works.

#### CSS

```
div {
    display    : block;
    position   : absolute;
    left       : 100px;
    right      : 0px;
    top        : 3px;
}

input {
    width      : 100%;  
    border     : 1px solid #000;
    background : #FFF;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDFnW/12/) using other examples.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDFnW/14/) all working.

#### Example

[image: Example]

You can get a similar effect (albeit not the same however) [using floats](http://jsfiddle.net/hDFnW/15/).

Comment: Arg, that's the problem with simplifying examples...  I actually need left:50, right:0.

Comment: @Mark Can you do a new jsFiddle with exactly what you want?

Comment: @alex -- thanks, I came up with the same thing.  I actually updated the fiddle a few minutes ago.  I need it to not be wrapped since it's external markup.  I don't get why this doesn't work in FF...

Comment: @Mark OK, I'll see if anything else works, stay tuned. Are you saying the HTML can not be changed at all, only the CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Very simple fix...no wrapping required. IE, Chrome, FF - all good.

http://jsfiddle.net/LGn9A/1/

don't mix the pixels w/ percentages  :-) (in this case)

```
ul {
    width       : 95%; /* here */
    font        : 12px/1.4 tahoma; /* global aethetics */
    ....
}

li { ... }

input, span {
    display    : block;
    position   : absolute;
    left       : 20%; /* here */
    right      : 0px;
    width      : 80%; /* and here */
}
```

<strike>FF-- will cooperate using `white-space:nowrap;` works in IE, and Chrome as well.</strike>

```
<li>Title
    <span style="border:0px">
        <input style="width:100%;left:0px;white-space:nowrap;">
    </span>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hDFnW/16/

Comment: This would lead the distance between the start and the end of the element be bigger and bigger while its parent grows up. The intention of the question seems to be keep a fixed value of 200px left, no matter the width of the parent. For this case, the solution would be http://stackoverflow.com/a/4577395/179138

Comment: Really? Because it looks like it's a **100px left** solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this problem is to use `position:relative` on input and assign its left position and width value using percentage and not `px`. That's because parent `ul` width is specified in percentage and not `px`. Otherwise the solution would be easy if a fixed width was given to the `ul` element

```
<ul>
    <li>Title<input></li>
    <li>Title<input></li>
</ul>

ul {
    width       : 95%;
    border      : 1px solid #000;
    font-family : tahoma;
    padding     : 5px;
    position:relative;
}

li {    
    background-color : #EEE;
    margin           : 2px;
    padding          : 3px;
}

input {     
    position:relative;
    left:20%;
    width:75%; /* I used 75% to give an extra 5% room for paddings and margins specified by parent elements ex: li ul) */
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/t5CvC/1/

Answer (score 1):

I came up with two solutions:

- http://jsfiddle.net/w6fGY/ - fixed width for `<span>` and `<input>`
- http://jsfiddle.net/B4MKu/ - all `<input>`s wrapped in `<span>` and `width:100%`.

I hope it's of use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [-moz-calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-calc) would work, but only in FF4.

As you said you don't want wrapper spans or divs.
There's a slightly hacky way in this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCZCm/3/)**

**Summary:**
Change the box-sizing model to contain borders and padding, then add the 100px as left padding so the input text value moves over but the width stays at 100%; - then **[clip](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html)** the input to chop off the extra left bit and show the title text again. Only problem is, there's no left border, I tried to add a fake one with a pseudo element.. needless to say the fake border doesn't work in IE8 and none of it works in IE7

#### Update

updated code to use a background image which now gives a border effect in IE too ==> **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCZCm/4/)**